# Google maps iOS sdk voice search for place

Tags: ios, google-maps

I've read through the Google Maps iOS documentation relating to searching for places (GMSMapView properties, GMSPlacePicker, GMSAutoCompletePrediction, etc.) but I can't find anything describing how to add a default search bar to a GMSMapView (similar to the one in the Google Maps iOS app).

In particular, I would like to offer the user the ability to search in the following ways:

- Type in place name with autocomplete
- Voice search for place name after clicking on microphone icon

I could develop develop the autocomplete list myself using the supplied sdks classes but this still doesn't help me with voice search.

Am I missing something or is this simply impossible to do using the current version of the SDK?

Comment: Voice search isn't part of the Maps SDK. You'll need to to implement voice recognition on your own. On [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#VoiceSearch), it's pretty easy. I'm not sure about iOS, but there are [third party frameworks](http://www.politepix.com/openears/#Basic_concepts) which can do a pretty good job.

Comment: Thanks! I will check those out!